# Stop CSS animation with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know why this isn't working? I just want my button to stop the background animation when it is clicked. Please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#togglebackgroundbutton").click(function(){
        $("-webkit-keyframes bg").toggleclass("paused");
    });
});

</script>
<style>
    body {
        background-color:green;
        -webkit-animation-name:bg;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes bg {
        from{background-color:green;}
        50%{background-color:yellow;}
        to{background-color:green;}
    }

    .paused {
        -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but I've never heard of a `<-webkit-keyframes><bg>Content</bg></-webkit-keyframes>` structure before :p

Comment: You cannot select CSS Styles, you have to select the element and toggle the class on/off of that.

Comment: check your specificity. Try changing `.paused` to an ID

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#togglebackgroundbutton").click(function(){
        $("body").toggleClass("paused");
    });
});
```

You should toggle class on body. Also its `toggleClass` and not `toggleclass`